# A Speedless Particle

Tags: particle-physics, speed-of-light, tachyon

A classification system for particles based on how fast they can go lists:

1. Bradyons - Particles that go less than the speed of light
2. Luxons - Particles that go at the speed of light
3. Tachyons - Particles that go faster than the speed of light

It occurred to me we have a category missing, what about a particle that cannot go at any speed whatsoever, a minimum speed particle (the opposite classification to a Luxon). I understand that Tachyons and what-ever-this-is-ons are not "real" particles, but rather math constructs. Rather, using the same steps that one would use with Tachyons, what would a particle that wen't the minimum speed for any observer act like? As a Luxon would always travel at the speed of light in any reference frame, would this always travel at 0c in any reference frame? Theoretically of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The categories you've listed are the only ones consistent with special relativity. If an object has $v=0$ in one reference frame, it will not have $v=0$ in any other frame. If something appears to be still to you and you start walking, it will no longer be still.

The speed $c$ is special, as the only invariant speed allowed in special relativity. You can't have two invariant speeds without giving up on the whole structure of the theory.

Comment: Got it. I can see how that would cause problems.